# Add a uuid4 header Haproxy

Tags: haproxy

As far as I can tell haproxy doesn't support setting a UUID as a header value, but I'm wondering if there's some method I have overlooked, maybe a lua script that could add a uuid value for a header if the header isn't present?

I have a header parameter x-request-id that is a uuid4 used to uniquely identify requests. This header can be set by the client. However not all clients set the header. Ideally I'd like to add this header in haproxy if it isn't present so the request can be tracked from the edge.

Answer (score 0):

HAProxy 2.1 introduced support for a `uuid` fetch, which supports uuid4